# Advantages/disadvantages for an app manager using either Node JS (desktop app) or iOS (mobile app)

Tags: ios, node.js, node-webkit

I have to make a report for my internship between these two technologie : Node JS (specially Node Webkit) and iOS.

The goal of the application is to synthesizes reviews of some applications from app store.

Right now I have collected some informations :

Nodes Web kit advantages :

- Program Once, run everywhere. (linux, mac Os and windows)
- Same rendering in every platform.
- Access to NPM
- No need to be approved on App Store
- Great liberty for design (css + html5)

Nodes Web kit disadvantages :

- Slow to start-up
- Hard to debug
- Few tools to develop
- Design must be responsive (not really but it's better)
- No visibility on app store
- No access to camera, geo, etc...
- Unprotected source code
- monothread
- Maybe harder to design.

Do you have some ideas about this ?

Thanks you !